# Is this kitchen partition wall load-bearing?

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing

I would like to remove the highlighted wall. I live in a condo built 30 yrs ago and there is another tenant the above my unit. the wall I want to remove seems where an old window and a door attached in the old days.

Please help me identify if its load bearing wall or not. I want to install floating counter top so that my dining room open to the kitchen without any barrier.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which way do the ceiling joists run? Are they parallel to this wall or perpendicular?

Comment: The floor plan does not relate to the photo.

Comment: What is the function of the grille in the wall?

Comment: It's possible that we're looking at a mirrored layout. Condos often have left and right designs that are essentially the same. Hanna, is that the case here? Things are backward.

Answer (score 2):

That section of the wall is not load bearing in the sense of holding up the upper floor that's for sure.

This little in-between section is drywall as it clearly houses an electrical component in.
loadbearing sections (for large structural parts of the building) are not allowed to have built-in electronics on them. Only external electronics.

It is just drywall.

[image: options]

HOWEVER there's two options I can see here as shown in the picture I add here:  Option A  could be that the upper part of both the window opening and the doorway opening are both of one piece, then that wall section you circled can safely be removed.

But if its open B then it means the window opening and the doorway have separate top parts and are supported by that center beam you circled.

And my uneducated guess is that is option A,  it looks like it used to be a completely closed room with a door  but got renovated to have an opening and that wall section is left there because of the wiring and switch would have had to be wired up elsewhere which seemed like a hassle so its left there.

These are just assumptions of course but that's what it looks like with the given information and floor plan. Which is what I think the closest thing to an answer I guess.

Comment: How do you know it isn't load bearing?

Comment: Yes, your opening assertion is rather *unsupported*, so to speak.